# Rails routing, index and show are the same?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I am building a gallery on my site and getting a bit stuck with the routing and associated actions in my controllers.

Basically I have three models: `Collection`, `Album` and `Photo`

A `Collection` can container other `Collection`s or `Albums` but NOT both. An `Album` then contains `Photo`s.

At my root `/gallery` path I route to the index view. This passes a list of Collections that have a nil parent_id set and the view displays. All well and good.

Now, I want to link those Collection titles so that the id of the collection is passed back in. At this point I would normally need to use the link helper of "gallery_collection_path" but that would direct to the show view. In my case it looks like the Index and Show view are the same until I get to a collection with Albums in which I would then be at the Album Index view instead.

Where I am getting stuck is how to structure this in my routes file and what the link_to's on the Collection names should look like.

Currently in my `routes.rb` file I have:

```
  namespace :gallery do
    get 'collections/:collection_id', to: 'collections#index'
    root to: 'collections#index'
  end
```

But I don't quite think this is right. I've tried to use `url_for` to generate the URL like so:

`<%= link_to collection.title, url_for(['gallery', 'collections', collection.id]) %>`

but I keep getting the following error:

`undefined method`to_model' for 71:Fixnum`

Can anyone possibly push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :gallery do
    resources :collections, only: [:index, :show] do
       resources :albums, only: [:show]
    end
end
```

And you can use url helpers:
index: `gallery_collections_path, gallery_collections_url`
show: `gallery_collection_path(id), gallery_collection_url(id)`

And for helper method **url_for**, you can reference here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for

Edit:
If you need to separate logics and view for Album and Collections, you need to define Album controller and set routing as above.

Comment: Thankyou, but what about when I get to albums? What actions do i use? Also what about the issue with the show action being the index action for a nested collection?

Comment: With the routes config above, show action won't be same with index action. But with your config `get 'collections/:collection_id', to: 'collections#index'` , show action will be routed to index action.

Comment: Yes but an album maybe be nested inside of a number of sub collections. A top level Collection will obviously be routed to Index to all all other top level collections but a second level one, is this to go to Index (to show all collections inside there or to Show as we are SHOWing that collection. This is my issue?

Comment: Collections#index will show all collections. It's not related to top level or not. When it comes show a collection, we will redirect user to Collections#show.

Comment: But surely Showing a collection will end up with the same view as the index view of a Collection (unless it contains albums, then it would be the index view of Album)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156696/discussion-between-ming-jin-and-rctneil).